# Overriding AdminTimeWidget for a different input_type

Tags: django

If i pick up the default `TimeInput` class i'm able to change the input type of the element rendered in the template, for example:

```
from django import forms

class TimeInput(forms.TimeInput):
    input_type = 'time'
```

If i use this widget, i'll get a `<input type="time">`.

However, if i try to override the `AdminTimeWidget`, which also descends from `TimeInput`, the element is rendered as `<input type="text">`.

Example:

```
class AdminTimeWidget(forms.TimeInput):
    input_type = 'time'

    class Media:
        js = [
            'admin/js/calendar.js',
            'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js',
        ]

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, format=None):
        attrs = {'class': 'vTimeField', 'size': '8', **(attrs or {})}
        super().__init__(attrs=attrs, format=format)

class CountTimeForm(forms.Form):
    from_time = forms.TimeField(widget = AdminTimeWidget(), required=False)
```

In here, the `from_time` input will be rendered as a text input... How can i fix it, in order to render as a time input?

Comment: did you try to override ```AdminTimeWidget``` ? like: ```class MyAdminTimeWidget(AdminTimeWidget)```?

Comment: That works but then the form loses the addons from the AdminTimeWidget. For example the "Now" button and the clock.